# java code for converting videos into byte arrays

Tags: java, video, arrays, frames

I am looking for a easy to use library in  java that can convert a video into arrays(corresponding to frames). Arrays will be used for frame processing with standard algos like GMM

Answer (score 1):

You should start out by trying the [**Java Media Framework**](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/).

You can find a sample project that uses the JMF APIs [at this link](http://www.exactfutures.com/index02.htm).